# How to update many by objectid in mongodb using go driver

Tags: mongodb, go, slice, objectid

I want to bulk update collection by slice of objectid

Here is the function for updatemany

```
func BulkDeleteEmailContentFieldByIds(ids []primitive.ObjectID) error {
    filter := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": ids}}
    update := bson.D{{"$unset", bson.D{{"email_content", 1}}}}
    result, err := collection.UpdateMany(ctx, filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    pp.Printf("Bulk delete removed %v document(s)\n", result.ModifiedCount)
    return nil
}

var trackingLogIds []primitive.ObjectID

for _, v := range userDocs {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(v bson.M) {
        defer wg.Done()
        // do something to return objectID
        trackingLogIds = append(trackingLogIds, emaDoc["_id"].(primitive.ObjectID))
    }(v)
}

emadb.BulkDeleteEmailContentFieldByIds(trackingLogIds)
```

Is the slice trackingLogIds is the correct way to search for documents with objectId

And is the query for updatemany i doing is right?
If not then how can i improve it.
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about your concern/question? Is the code producing the intended output? If so, what are you looking to change with it? If not, what is it doing instead of what you'd like for it to do?

Comment: I had update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had test the function i provided and its working as expected.

Find all document in slice of objectid and unset the field email_content

---

Comment: please add the updated code to clarify your response